# How to set different logging levels in openelemetry-java?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-cloud-sleuth, open-telemetry

We are planning to use open-telemetry as the logging tool in a new Spring-boot based micro-service. We have explored two ways to use otel, first is using manual instrumentation provided by Java and other is using Spring-cloud-sleuth using `@NewSpan` annotation
However, I could not find a way to specify different logging levels like INFO/ERROR/DEBUG. We need to have an ability to control and restrict the excessive logging. However, additional debug logs can help in troubleshooting if required.
How can we set the logging levels with open-telemetry java or spring-sleuth?

Uodate: As commented by @Jan , I was getting confused between tracing and logging. However, I can not find any documentation about support for logging with opentelemetry-java. Is there any way to do it? Also, if we use different tools for tracing and logging, will it be considered a bad practice?

Comment: It looks like you don't understand difference between `logging` (`log` entity) and `tracing` (`trace` entity) and you are trying to have log level on tracing.

Comment: Yes....I am quite new to the concept of tracing. So generally how do we use combination of tracing and logging? Can we use different frameworks for both? For example, if we use  open-telemetry for tracing and slf4j/log4j for logging, will it be considered a bad practice?

Comment: I would say that will be a good start. Opentelemetry is concept for metrics, traces, logs. Unfortunately, Opentelemetry logs implementation is only alpha, so is better to use standard log libraries for logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So generally how do we use combination of tracing and logging? Can we use different frameworks for both? For example, if we use open-telemetry for tracing and slf4j/log4j for logging, will it be considered a bad practice?

OpenTelemetry will never have a "logging" API meant to be used by ordinary users, it is supposed to capture logs produced by actual logging libraries (like log4j or logback).

OpenTelemetry support for logs is still in the alpha state (meaning that the logging SPI/SDK might still change in non-backward compatible ways), but we already have dedicated OpenTelemetry appenders for several of the most commonly used logging libraries, like [log4j](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/log4j/log4j-appender-2.17/library) or [logback](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/logback/logback-appender-1.0/library). You should be able to use these and expect relatively little breaking changes.

Comment: Is there no support for slf4j available with OpenTelemetry appenders?

Comment: Just the slf4j-api? No, we don't have that -- we instrument (probably) all the actual logging implementations, like logback or log4j instead. You can use slf4j with e.g. log4j and the agent (or the manually configured appender, if you're not using the javaagent) will capture all the logs.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the confirmation